# Selecting folder name by click event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to select between two folders depending what the user clicks. 
I need to implement it in java script..because its dummy code of another long code.
if user select 'Folder1'   -> folder 1
if user select 'Folder2'   -> folder 2

I don't know how can I implement it.

```
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: #000000;
                margin: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }



            #box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>


        <h2>Spectacular Mountain</h2>
<img src="folder1/1.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">

        <div id='box'></div>
        <div id='buttons'>
         <button id='Fl1'>Folder1</button>
        <button id='Fl2'>Folder2</button>
        </div>



        <script type="text/javascript">

var box = document.getElementById('box');

document.getElementById('buttons').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    var target = evt.target;
    var folderid=1;// to initiat
    if (target.id === 'Fl1') {
        box.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        // DUMMY 2 understand what I want
        I need to get name of folder
    folderid=1;
    } else if (target.id === 'Fl2') {
        box.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        // DUMMY 2 understand what I want
        folderid=2;
    } else {
        box.style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
    }
}, false);

// How CAN I write folder name and display image

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `target.getAttribute('id')` instead of `target.id` to get attribute value :

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');

document.getElementById('buttons').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  var target = evt.target;
  var folderid=1;// to initiat

  if (target.getAttribute('id') === 'Fl1') {
    box.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    // DUMMY 2 understand what I want I need to get name of folder
    folderid=1;
  } else if (target.getAttribute('id') === 'Fl2') {
    box.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    // DUMMY 2 understand what I want
    folderid=2;
  } else {
    box.style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
  }
}, false);
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/0ngsdzx2/